# how to draw a line and be able to drag it from screen in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-canvas

i'm new in android ..  and i'm just thinking on a way to draw a line
on background ?....
and from user perspective, he will able to move the line but only the part that was clicked and dragged.
like move straight line to banana shape (curve it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a custom view.  You can do the dragging by catching and processing touch events and invalidating the view.  Then in the onDraw you draw the correct shape based on the last touch event.

Comment: you mean, i will have line on screen ... then the User will draw some line on screen 
and the existing line will change it shape according to the touch of user 
can you show code example for it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/verticalLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"        
        android:background="@color/white" <!-- change the color of your line -->
/>
```